# Is it true for all smooth closed curve on a plane that at least there exists one point where its normal line bisects the circumference of the curve?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Is it true for all smooth closed curve on a plane that at least there exists one point where its normal line bisects the circumference of the closed curve?

If we denote a smooth closed curve on a plane as $\Gamma$ , obviously there exists a bijective function $f:\Gamma\to\Gamma$ such that the chord $Pf(P)$ divides $\Gamma$ into arcs of equal length for all $P\in\Gamma$ , let $Q=f(P)$ . Then the above problem is equivalent to proving the existence of $PQ$ which is also the normal of $\Gamma$ at either $P$ or $Q$ for all $\Gamma$ .

*Due to my ignorance of diffrential geometry and topology, the definitions of this question may be inappropriate and imprecise. Any discussions are welcomed.*

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by *bisects the circumference*?

Comment: Already the statement that $Pf(P) $ bisects $\Gamma$ needs some clarification, in my opinion. Are you considering arc length and are searching for a cord which divides $\Gamma$ into arcs of equal length?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The definition of bisecting the circumference is exactly the same as what Thomas commented.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, exactly.

Comment: Restricting the question to smooth convex curves is still an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

**COMMENT**: What is the meaning of the question if the normal lines intersect the curve in more than two points? Must you find a normal line that intersects precisely twice, or does the line bisect if *one* of the intersection points gives a bisection?

**HINTS**: Orient the curve once and for all. For each $p\in\Gamma$, consider the intersection of the normal line at $p$ with $\Gamma$. Let $q$ be the intersection point farthest away from $p$ (measuring distance along $\Gamma$). Let $f_1(p)$ be the distance (arclength) from $p$ to $q$ moving forward along $\Gamma$, and let $f_2(p)$ be the distance moving backward along $\Gamma$. Set $f(p)=f_1(p)-f_2(p)$. Your charge is to prove that $f$ is continuous.

Next, let me suggest that you show there is $\bar p\in\Gamma$ so that the tangent lines at $\bar p$ and $\bar q$ are parallel. (Note that you can write $q(p)=p+\lambda(p)N(p)$. Parametrize $p$ by arclength of $\Gamma$ and differentiate.)

Why does it now follow that $f(P)=0$ for some $P\in\Gamma$?

Comment: The line bisects if one of the intersection points gives a bisection. And about the *hint* part, the continous of $f$ is obvious, yet to use the Intermediate Value Theorem, we need to show that there exists some $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $f(p_1)\cdot f(p_2)<0$ . That's where the *normal line* property is to be used, else if you consider a circle, and change *normal* into *the line forms a 45 degree angle between its tangent line* , then $f(p)>0 \forall p\in\Gamma$ .